# rsync error: when using source which contain "*" character

Tags: tcl, rsync

In my TCL script I use rsync command and unfortunately it is refusing to sync path contain "*" character.

Code Example:

```
 set srs "/users/home/username/common/*"
 catch {exec  rsync -av $src /tmp} res
 puts $res
```

Output:

```
 building file list ... done

 sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
 total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
 rsync: link_stat "/users/home/username/common/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
 rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at main.c(977) [sender=2.6.9]
    while executing
  "exec  rsync -rLptgov  $src /tmp "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of writing that is:

```
set srs "/users/home/username/common/*"
catch {exec rsync -av {*}[glob $src] /tmp} res
puts $res
```

This is because Tcl doesn't expand glob metacharacters by default; it's safer that way and easier to write correct code (it's *hard* to write good shell code that is resistant to problems in this area) but it does mean that you need to do a little extra work. The extra work is:

1. Ask for glob expansion of `$srs` with the `glob` command. That returns a list.
2. Ask for expansion of the list out of the `glob` by using the `{*}` pseudo-operator (it's not an operator — it's technically a kind of syntax — but it works a lot like one).

---

If you're using Tcl 8.4 (or before!) then you do it a bit different way:

```
set srs "/users/home/username/common/*"
catch {eval [list exec rsync -av] [glob $src] [list /tmp]} res
puts $res
```

OK, that's <s>sometimes</s> often shortened by leaving out the `list` bits (and there are many more obscure ways of writing it!) but that's a bad habit as it can cause huge problems when dealing with variables with values that aren't “nice”, e.g., with spaces in pathnames. If you have 8.5 or later, use `{*}`. Really.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what [GrAnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653311/grand) said, you have to build the list of source files explicitly, probably using `glob`, so you'd do it like this

```
set cmd [concat [list exec rsync -av] \
                [glob -nocomplain /users/home/username/common/*]]
lappend cmd /tmp
catch {eval $cmd} res
puts $res
```

or, alternatively, use `{*}` to expand the agument list for `exec` (this is for Tcl >= 8.5), like this:

```
set cmd [concat [list rsync -av] \
                [glob -nocomplain /users/home/username/common/*]]
lappend cmd /tmp
catch {exec {*}$cmd} res
puts $res
```

**Update:** fixed example so that it really works.

Comment: I found that the GrAnd example is which ine what is working for me

Comment: I found that the GrAnd example is which one what was work for me:

*catch {exec csh -c "/usr/local/bin/rsync -av $src $dest"} res*

The solution used explicitly list was not finish correctly

**cmd:**
 */usr/local/bin/rsync -av /users/home/username/common/RCS /users/home/username/common/1 /users/home/username/common/2 /users/home/username/common/3 /tmp*

**result:**

*couldn't execute "/usr/local/bin/rsync -av /users/home/username/common/RCS /users/home/username/commo": no such file or directory*

Comment: @rkaganov, sorry, that was my fault: `exec` expects its arguments passed to it "as is", not a single argument which is a list.  So I fixed my example so that it should now work: the first variation embeds `exec` to the command spec and then `eval`'s it while the second expands the constructed list of arguments using the `{*}` syntactic thing appeared in Tcl 8.5.

Comment: @rkaganov, the problem with @GrAnd's approach is that you pass your command through the shell. This has two implications: 1) now your command's *string* goes through the shell expansion--look at your invocation and think what happens if `$src` or `$dest` would happen to have a space character embedded in them, or a semicolon.  If your program gets `$src` and/or `$dest` as a user input, this even opens up a possibility for an exploit; 2) This is one more process to fork+exec. Not a big deal, but still...

Answer (score 0):

That's because tcl interpreter does not expand the '*' symbol as shell does.

For example:

```
$ tclsh
% cd /usr
% exec ls -d *
ls: *: No such file or directory
% exec sh -c "ls -d *"
X11R6
bin
docs
etc
...
```